# JSP: Generate unique HTML class names in a c:otherwise loop (100% newbie)

Tags: html, css, jsp

First of all, I don't know what I'm doing. I don't even know if I have the programming language correct. (I know it's a JSP file I'm editing.) I'm a web designer that has always focused on HTML, CSS, and graphics programs. I searched the web for a long time for an answer to this question, but couldn't find one. Probably because I don't even know the right terms to search for. So...sorry in advance. :)

I'm trying to make a small change to my company's online store. On our product listing pages, we have a 3x8 grid of divs displaying 24 products per page. It's generated within an "forEach/otherwise" loop, if that's even the right term. Here's the stripped-down code I'm trying to affect:

```
<c:otherwise>
    <div class="prod-record">
</c:otherwise>
```

I want to generate an ordered sequence of unique classes within the div tag, so I can style specific cells of the grid. I imagine it would look something like this:

```
<div class="prod-record cell<c:out value="sequence of numbers"/>">
```

So it would generate HTML that would look like:

```
<div class="prod-record cell1">
<div class="prod-record cell2">
<div class="prod-record cell3">
<div class="prod-record cell4">
```

And so on.

I've been trying to figure this out all day, but I just have no clue.

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
   <div class="prod-record cell<c:out value='${i}'/>">
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Hmm...doesn't seem to be working for me.

My forEach is in a separate file, if that matters.